# Connecting two classes of objects so that the total connection distance is minimal

Tags: algorithm

Imagine a map with **n cities** randomly placed on it. On the same map, there are also **m people**, randomly placed on the map. n and m do not have any restrictions (other than being a positive integer of course). You need to assign every person to a city (a city can have multiple people assigned to it) so that the total distance travelled by all people combined is as low as possible AND all cities must have at least one person assigned to them. If `m<n`, you need to assign all people to different cities.

What would be the most efficient algorithm for this?

As an example: in the following image the red lines are the best solution, while the blue lines are suboptimal.
[image: example]

Comment: There has to be something else, such as which person wants to meet which. Otherwise, we could just cram all the people in one city and everybody's happy. Give more details, please.

Comment: So, did you try to assign each people to the closest city?

Comment: @user189 sorry, seems I forgot yet another requirement. All cities must have at least one person assigned to them. If m<n, you need to assign all people to different cities.

Comment: Ok, then did you check this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) is a special case of this problem where m = n (assuming that the distances can be arbitrary). As user189 notes, the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is a cubic-time algorithm for the assignment problem, though there are heuristics likely to improve on the performance of the HA in practice. If m > n, then we can add m - n dummy cities whose distance to each person is the distance from that person to the closest city. Each person matched with a dummy city is assigned its closest city. If m < n, then we can add n - m dummy people at distance 0 from each city. The dummy people simply are ignored in determining the final assignment.